# Confusing this.el in backbone.js with subviews

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I've a big problem with subviews in backbone.js.
I've two views and I want to render the second one into an element of the first one.
So i defined `this.el` in the second view which is referenced to a section (section#user-data) in the first view.

I create an object of the second view **after first view has been rendered** and if i write
`alert($('#user-data').length)` before I create my object I get a **1** so it exists.

But inside the second view I get an undefined.
If I log `this.el` in any method.
But if I use e.g. body for `this.el` everything works as expected.

What's the reason for that?

Example:

```
   /**
     * The example of a view for profile's component
     *
     *
     * @module Profile
     * @submodule Frontend
     * @class ProfileView
     * @constructor
     *
     */
    ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // The tagname wrapping the rendered content
        // The template for the current view
        template : _.template('COMPONENTS_VIEW_FRAME'),

        /**
         * The initialisation for the current view (kind of constructor)
         *
         * @method initialize
         */
        initialize : function() {
        },

        /**
         * The rendering process for the current view
         *
         * @method render
         * @param {String} oLocas the data to render inside this view
         */
        render : function(oLocas) {

            $(this.el).html(this.template(oLocas));

            return this;
        }
    });

           /**
     * The example of a view for profile's component
     *
     *
     * @module Profile
     * @submodule Frontend
     * @class ProfileView
     * @constructor
     *
     */
    ProfileSectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // The tagname wrapping the rendered content

        // The template for the current view
        template : _.template('COMPONENTS_VIEW_OPTION_SECTION'),

        el : $('#user-data'),

        events : {
            'click a.open_close_section' : 'doIt'
        },

        headline : 'ddd',

        /**
         * The initialisation for the current view (kind of constructor)
         *
         * @method initialize
         */
        initialize : function() {
            alert($(this.el).length);
        },

        doIt : function(event) {
            alert('jo');
        },

/**
         * The rendering process for the current view
         *
         * @method render
         * @param {String} eventName the name of the triggered event
         */
        render : function(oLocas) {

            $(this.el).html(this.template(oLocas));

            return this;
        }
    });
            // Here I start to use the first view
            var oProfileView = new ProfileView();

                $('#profile').html(oProfileView.render().el).fadeIn(500,    function() {

                    $(this).removeClass('closed');
                                            // Here I create the second view
                    var oProfileSectionView = new ProfileSectionView({
                        model : this.model
                    });

                    oProfileSectionView.render({
                        headline : 'XXX',
                        sectionrows : 'ddd'
                    }).el;

                });
```

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Added some example code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little gotcha with JavaScript.

JavaScript is looking for that element when you're *defining* `ProfileSelectionView`. So this:

```
ProfileSectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    el : $('#user-data'),
    // ...
});
```

Is actually being evaluated right there in the definition of `ProfileSelectionView`, not later on when you instantiate an instance of `ProfileSelectionView`.

To fix this, move the defining of `el` into the initialization:

```
ProfileSectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    // Do not define the el here. I've commented it out
    // el : $('#user-data'),
    // ...
    initialize : function() {
        this.setElement($('#user-data'));
    },
    // ...
});
```

Or even better, you can just pass the element in when creating the `ProfileSelectionView` (as noted in the [Backbone.js docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor)):

```
var oProfileView = new ProfileView();

$('#profile').html(oProfileView.render().el).fadeIn(500,    function() {
    // ...
    var oProfileSectionView = new ProfileSectionView({
        model : this.model,
        el: $('#user-data')
    });
    // ...
});
```

By doing it this way, you don't have to define an `initialize` function in `ProfileSelectionView`.

Comment: No problem, very happy to help.